# Wordpress plugin Responsive Slick Slider

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi im trying to get my slider responsive, i have two issues, one, i tried changing the row width in the editor code and still doesnt change, also id like to know if anyone knows how to remove the video controls with this plugin.

Comment: Generally... If a slider doesn't support responsiveness, then it would likely be a really big deal to make it responsive. Like not too far from just building a new slider from scratch. — Based on the name, the one you are using probably does... and it's just not working for whatever reason. You may want to: read the documentation, contact the developer or try another plugin. Either way – this is probably going to get closed because the question is kinda poorly formatted and it doesn't really have much to do with code unless you're looking to drastically change the plugin functionality.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Slick slider supports responsive breakpoints. This example below is taken directly from their documentation:

```
$('.yoursliderclass').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```